# Intern functional testing and clearing cookies with before and after

Tags: javascript, testing, promise, intern

Writing a series of functional tests using intern, and I was trying to use the before and after methods to clear out all cookies and locally stored data so each test starts clean.

Here's the cleanEnvironment function I'm trying to use, located in a module called `utils`:

```
cleanEnvironment: function(name) {

    name = name || 'NONE';

    // window params
    var defaultHeight = 768;
    var defaultWidth  = 1024;

    if (this.remote.environmentType.webStorageEnabled === true) {
        this.remote
            .clearSessionStorage()
            .clearLocalStorage();
    }

    return this.remote
        .setWindowSize(defaultWidth, defaultHeight)
        .getCookies()
        .then(
            function(cookies) {
                console.log('in ', name);
                console.log('Existing cookies that will be cleared are  ', cookies);
            }
        )
        .clearCookies()
        .then(
            function(cookies) {
                console.log('in ', name);
                console.log('Existing cookies are  ', cookies);
            }
        );

},
```

and here's how I'm trying to call it in the before/after methods:

```
after: function() {
    console.log('timestamp for login after start is ', Date.now());
    utils.cleanEnvironment.call(this, 'login before');
    console.log('timestamp for login after finish is ', Date.now());
},
```

I finally realized (and reread the docs that say this) that I can't be assured of the order of before and after for multiple suites, because I'm not returning a Promise in those modules. But I'm struggling to write a promise that allows me to use this external module `utils` so I'm not repeating code in each suite.

What would a promise in the `before`/`after` methods look like that successfully passes and returns the correct reference to `this.remote`? I'm not finding any examples of promises in these methods, and so far I either get errors in the `cleanEnvironment` function where `this.remote` is undefined, or the browser never loads the test URL, which I'm taking to mean I'm never resolving the promise.

Here's one of my attempts:

```
        after: function() {
            var self = this;
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                console.log('timestamp for login after start is ', Date.now());
                utils.cleanEnvironment.call(self, 'login before');
                console.log('timestamp for login after finish is ', Date.now());
                resolve();
            });
        },
```

I'm sure I'm completely missing something obvious about Promises, but after 7 hours of staring at this code, I'm blind to whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

A Command is promise-like, and can be used for async operations, so you can just return the result of your `cleanEnvironment` function in the `after` method.

```
after: function () {
    return utils.cleanEnvironment(...)
}
```

You should also take care to maintain a single chain in `cleanEnvironment`. In the original `cleanEnvironment`, two separate chains may be started, and only the second is returned. If the first took longer to run than the second for some reason, Intern wouldn't wait for it to complete. To keep the chain continuous, do something like:

```
var chain = this.remote;

if (this.remote.environmentType.webStorageEnabled === true) {
    chain = this.remote
        .clearSessionStorage()
        .clearLocalStorage();
}

return chain
    .setWindowSize(defaultWidth, defaultHeight)
    .getCookies()
    // ...
```